# error even after following Microsoft format in SQL

Tags: sql, string, t-sql

How to output a string without a heading? My code looks pretty fine but the error message says:-  "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' and was born ' to data type int."

And I'm not even trying to change that character string into an 'int' then why did it interpret that way?

```
SELECT FirstName + ' has a EmployeeID of '+ EmployeeID + ' and was born '+ 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), BirthDate, 112)
FROM Db.Employees;
```

A similar code shown in Microsoft page however works:-

```
SELECT 'The order is due on ' + CONVERT(varchar(12), DueDate, 101) 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader  
WHERE SalesOrderID = 50001;
```

Answer (score 2):

You must convert EmployeeID, which is int, to varchar. Try to change your code like this:

```
SELECT FirstName + ' has a EmployeeID of '+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), EmployeeID) + ' and was born '+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), BirthDate, 112)
FROM Db.Employees;
```

If you look at [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL Server, you will see that int data type (#16) is above string types (#25-#28), thus SQL Server will try to convert the text (employee's name, etc.) to int.

Another option is to use [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to concatenate your values.